# NodeJS Memory Issues in Array.map()

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, memory

### Overview

I am experiencing some strange behavior using an async map function in NodeJs on AWS lambda, and I would love some direction on why this is occurring.

I have recreated the situation in the code block below with a toy example of the code that is giving me the errors.

The topLevel() function has an array of objects. The function calls Array.map() on the array, and passes in an async helper function to the map function. The helper function performs some transformations to the object, and one of those transformations is to encrypt the bank account nested object. This is done with another async helper function (encryptBank).

### The Bug

In the return value of the topLevel function, the bank account for the user with id="abc" has the encrypted bank account object from the user with id="def". User with id="def" has the correct encrypted bank account object.

What could cause this to happen? Is there a problem with calling an async function from an async map function? Is using an async function in Array.map() a bad idea? Any tips would be appreciated as this bug has been driving me crazy.

### Environment information

Running on AWS Lambda with a NodeJS (version 12) runtime.

### Code

```
// This is the lambda handler
module.exports.topLevel = async () {
  const users = [
      {
        id: 'abc',
        name: 'George P. Burdell',
        job: 'Jack of all trades',
        married: true,
        bankInformation: {
            institution: 'Bank of America',
            routingNumber: 987654321,
            accountNumber: 665471235774
        }
      },
      {
        id: 'def',
        name: 'Jay-Z',
        job: 'Artist',
        married: true,
        bankInformation: {
            institution: 'Chase',
            routingNumber: 123456789,
            accountNumber: 97822651348 
        }
      }
  ]

  const transformedUsers = await Promise.all(users.map(helper))
  return transformedUsers

}

async function helper(o) {
    Object.Keys(o).forEach((k) => {
        if (k === 'bankInformation') {
            o[k] = await encryptBank(o[k])
            await s3.putObject({Body: JSON.stringify(o[k]),Bucket: bankBucketName, Key: `${o.id.toLowerCase()}.json`}).promise()
        } else if (k === 'married') {
            o[k] = !o[k]
        }
        else {
            o[k] = k.toUpperCase()
        }
    })
    return o
}

async function encryptBank(o) {
    Object.Keys(o).forEach((k) => {
        o[k] = await encrypt(o[k])
    })
    return o
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant really follow your example and how it relates to the bug, however, this smells of an incorrectly generated AWS Lambda function (to rule this out, run local tests on your code)

Sometimes state from one request can bleed into the state of another in AWS Lambda.

The reason for this is that AWS Lambda may re-use lambdas after they have been spun up. This means that any variables etc that you define outside your handler code will persist from one call to the next.

To avoid this problem, dont create variables outside your handler function, and ensure any imported/required modules dont save state. If they do, import them within your handler function, instead of at the top of your script. NOTE: this may increase lambda invocation time and therefore cost.

Comment: The example code shows how the different function calls occur in the users.map() stack trace. The lambda is configured correctly. In production, the 'users' array is an array of stream events from a dynamoDb table. When there is only one event, the function works as intended. When there are multiple events, sometimes it works as intended, and sometimes we get the bug described in the original post. 

The required modules etc are imported correctly, and this function does not reference any variables outside the handler or helper function scopes.

Comment: If the code as you have written it above works fine in local testing, you'll need to monitor dynamo streams input into lambda. You may be incorrectly updated dynamo further upstream which is providing incorrect stream data to your lambda. Basically if your code passes unit tests, its an upstream issue that you need to fix

Comment: I have monitored the streams sent into lambda. The data from the streams are correct, I have reviewed the cloudwatch logs and verified the new/old images from the stream events. The issue is almost certainly around memory management by node. I am far from an expert with async and map interactions, and really think it is an issue with that.

Comment: @AlexKetchum test test test. Thats all i can suggest. If its an issue with node, it should hopefully appear in local unit tests

Comment: @AlexKetchum another suggestion that may help find the bug. De-optimize your code i.e. remove the map function and use basic for loops. I find sometimes this can help clear things up. If you can get it to work without map, its at least some progress in the right direction - "Make it work, make it right, make it fast" - Kent Beck